# Web Service SOAP Message Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a case where i need to route a Web Service SOAP message through an intermediary server. Can anyone point me in the direction of some good resources on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

WSE is obsolete and should not be used unless there is no other choice.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on your answer.

Comment: @Canoehead: What more is there to say?

Comment: anon is looking for good resources and you've essentially answered with what would be a bad resource but no good ones. Maybe you should have put your answer as a comment to Andrew Hare's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to set up a WSE router?  If so [here is a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528755.aspx).

Comment: WSE is obsolete and should not be used unless there is no other choice.